# How do run a specific command as a user in a group

Tags: linux

As the jupyterhub user I'm trying to run a command as a user in the mgrs group.

```
$ cat /etc/group
mgrs:x:1011:cody,admin
$ cat /etc/sudoers
jupyterhub ALL=(%mgrs) NOPASSWD:/boot/tp/python3/bin/sudospawner
$ whoami
jupyterhub
$ sudo -u cody /boot/tp/python3/bin/sudospawner
Password:
```

The example for this sudoers line is from https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/wiki/Using-sudo-to-run-JupyterHub-without-root-privileges

Comment: Are you sure that works? It looks like on `cody` and `admin` belong to the `mgrs` group. That may be legal in the sudoers world, but if the command you are trying to run is only executable by members of `mgrs` and is not owned by `jupyterhub`, that is where I would start looking.

Comment: I set the permissions to be 777 on the executable for testing.

Comment: That eliminates that issue. I guess you have reason for not wanting to `setgid` for the group `mgrs` on the file so it always runs as `mgrs`?

Comment: I want to run a command as a specific user. In this case for jupyterhub so that users can read each other's files. I want the jupyterhub user to be able to run sudospawner as any user in the mgrs group. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: In that case you should be able to set the file ownership `sudo chown jupyterhub:mgrs /boot/tp/python3/bin/sudospawner` to set the UID to `jupyterhub` and GID to `mgrs`. Then make the file `setuid` , e.g. `chmod 4750 /boot/tp/python3/bin/sudospawner` so that all members of `mgrs` can run the file and it will run as user `jupyterhub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was permissions. The sudoers itself was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have your configuration backwards.  You are logged in as `jupyterhub` and trying to run it as `cody` - your config allows the opposite.  You also have a space between `NOPASSWD` and `:<command>` - you need to remove that space.  You should then able (with your config) to do this:

`$ whoami
cody
$ sudo -u jupyterhub /boot/tp/python3/bin/sudospawner`

If not, you should try removing the shell and any password from `jupyterhub` and not using that as a login user.  Login as cody and try the above.  Alternatively, create a new user with no shell (or maybe `/bin/false`) and no password and use that in place of `jupyterhub`.

What you posted as your desired purpose in your last comment above is the exact opposite of what you've implemented.

Comment: I get a password prompt when I do that.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice catch on the space, but that was a formatting problem of this post.

Comment: k, but your config and stated purpose are still at complete odds with one another - that's my main point. :)

Comment: What should be in sudoers?